# My redux saga is printing undefined state with useSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have this saga that makes a http request and make a dispatch in reducer:

```
// worker Saga: will be fired on GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST actions
function* fetchFiliais(action) {
    try {
        const data = yield call(LoginServices.fetchFiliaisApi);
        yield put(allActions.loginActions.receiveFilialData(data));
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({type: 'FETCH_FILIAIS_FAILED', message: e.message})
    }
}

/*
  Starts fetchFiliais on each dispatched `GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST` action.
*/

export default function* loginSaga() {
    yield takeEvery("GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST", fetchFiliais);
}
```

In my login component i'm calling this saga:

```
const Login = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const filiais = useSelector(state => state.filiais)
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({type: 'GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST'})
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log(filiais); }, 5000);
  }, [dispatch, filiais])
```

This is my reducer:
In my console.log() is printing the correct type and payload, and is printing "enter correct case":

```
const currentUser = (state = {}, action) => {
    console.log(action.type)
    console.log(action.payload)

    switch(action.type){
        case "SET_USER":
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload,
                loggedIn: true
            }
        case "LOG_OUT":
            return {
                ...state,
                user: {},
                loggedIn: false
            }
        case "RECEIVE_FILIAL_DATA":
            console.log('enter correct case')
            return {
                ...state,
                filiais: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
```

But i put one setTimeOut to console.log the variable filiais and this value is undefined.
Why?

This is my **index.js**:

```
import loginSaga from './pages/login/login-form/saga'

// create the saga middleware
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
)

// then run the saga
sagaMiddleware.run(loginSaga)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Router>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is my root reducer:

```
import currentUser from './login'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    currentUser
})

export default rootReducer
```

Answer (score 1):

> But i put one setTimeOut to console.log the variable filiais and this value is undefined. Why?

Because `filiais` is a local variable `const`. It's not possible to change the value of a `const`, and that's not what dispatching the action is trying to do anyway.

By dispatching the action you are, eventually, instructing the component to rerender. When it rerenders, a new local variable will be created, which will be assigned the new value. If you'd like to log the new value, put your log statement into the body of the component.

```
const filiais = useSelector(state => state.filiais)
console.log(filiais);
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({type: 'GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST'});
}, [dispatch])
```